# Accessing the viewstate of a child control

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I want to extract information in the viewstate of a child control. This control belongs to a third party and i do not have access to the source code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The viewstate is stored as base64.  If you can get the clientID of the control; you can mine it out from Form.Post["__VIEWSTATE"] by decoding it, and process it from there.